# How to make a new list from a lists first and last item Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have this code:

```
fnl list = [x | x <- list, x==list!!((length list)-1)]
```

which gives me the last item of an array. How can i improve this to get the first item also?

Comment: Why not just `fnl list = [head list, last list]`?

Comment: Note you are working with lists, and not arrays.

Comment: @Michail that's an answer, as long as you add some additional explanation.

Comment: BTW, the code you posted does not give you only the last element of a list, try e.g. `fnl [1,3,1,5,1]` which results in `[1,1,1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be

```
fnl list = [head list, last list]
```

`head` gives you the first element of a list, `last` gives the last one. This way you can avoid both indexing into the list (which generally should be avoided, especially if you have an option of using Prelude functions, as in this case) and getting its length.